# Optical Communication APD problem

Tags: digital-communications

A germanium APD (with $x= 1.0$) operates at a wavelength of $1.35μm$ where its responsivity is $0.45AW^{-1} $. The dark current is $200nA$ at the operating temperature of $250K$ and the device capacitance is $3 pF$. Determine the maximum possible SNR when the incident optical power is $8 × 10^{-7} W$ and the post-detection band-width without equalization is $560MHz$.

I tried solving this question. I'm attaching the MATLAB code I used for solving this problem.

If the code seems tedious. I did the following steps:

1. I computed load resistor $R_L$ first from Bandwidth
2. Secondly I computed quantum efficiency $\eta$ from Reponstivity
3. Then Optimum Multiplication factor $M$
4. Then I used the computed the multiplication factor to figure out $SNR_{dB}$

My answers pops out as $18.64 dB$ whereas textbook solution says its $23.9 dB$

Code:

```
clc;
clear;
close;
x=1;
lambda=1.35e-6;      %wavelength
R=0.45;              %Responstivity
Id=200e-9;           %Dark Current
T=250;               %Temparature
Cd=3e-12;            %Device Capcitance
Po=8e-7;             %Incident Optical Power
B=560e6;             %Bandwidth
e=1.602e-19;         %electron charge
h=6.626e-34;         %Plank Constant
c=2.998e8;                                     %Speed of light
K=1.381e-23;                                    %Boltzmann Constant
RL=1/(2*pi*B*Cd);                               %Load Resistor
n=(1.24*R)/(lambda*10^6);                       %quantum efficiency
Ip=(n*e*Po*lambda)/(h*c);                       %Photo current
Mop=((4*K*T)/(x*e*RL*(Ip+Id)))^(1/(2+x));       %Multiplication Factor
S=Mop^2*Ip^2;                         %Signal Power
N1=2*e*B*(Ip+Id)*Mop^(2+x);           %Shot Noise
N2=(4*K*T*B)/RL;                      %Thermal Noise
N=N1+N2;                              %Total Noise
SNR=S/N                               %SNR in natural unit
SNR_dB=10*log10(SNR)                  %SNR in dB
```

Comment: Can you replace that link to a pictiure of text on an off-site thing that does not interact nicely with my webtracking blocker – simply by typing the text into your question?

Comment: Also, hi! And welcome here! This is a "question and answers" site, and you forgot to actually ask a *precise question*!

Comment: since it had math expression, I though it'd be better to post the picture. But I'm adding the question.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've updated the question with the problem

Comment: you stated your homework problem, but you have not asked a question of your own

Comment: I'm getting the answer wrong. I think I clearly wrote that in a different paragraph, maybe read the complete post?

Comment: I read it. Where is your **question**? "I don't get the same result" is not a question. If the question is "What's wrong with my solution?" then I'll carefully point out that *we don't know*; we would have to go, just like you, to check all your intermediate results :)

Comment: Yeah, that was my question, I'll do a better job framing it next time, but can you point out what's wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I really can't. I would have to hit the books just like you and check every single line of your code against the theory – and we would not even be basing our understanding on the same representation of the theory, so I think we'd not get very far that way.  :(